# Android: How to use function given by Activity in Service

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service

I am new to Android and am developing an application where my widget displays Location latlong. I am doing this with configuration activity. Same location refreshes on refresh button. All is working fine but Activity screen flashes on widget. I want same output from service so that activity screen does not flash in front.

For this purpose I have created a service which launches on refresh button click but now how can I code as I used Map view, Location manager etc which service don't allow.

Comment: I don't think I understand this question. Could you please describe it in a bit more detailed way?

Comment: Previously I was calling an activity on refresh button click, which finds latest LAT LONG and update the widget. It works fine but activity screen flashes before updating a widget. Now i want to use service instead of Activity for this purpose.. But problem is I was using Location Manger & Map view etc in activity code to find location but in service these are not allowed.

Comment: You certainly can use `LocationManager` inside `Service` :)

Answer (score 0):

In your service you could use something like this:

```
    private void startPositionListener() {
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            // Get the location manager
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
        try {
            gpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            networkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        if(gpsEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 6000, 1, mGpsListener);
            Log.d(TAG, "GPS Listener started.");
        } else if(networkEnabled) { // Checking for GSM
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 6000, 1, mNetworkListener);
            Log.d(TAG, "Network Listener started.");
        }
}
```

Where `mNetworkListener` and `mGpsListener` are of class that implement `LocationListener`. The only method you'd have to fill is `onLocationChanged(Location)` (that's where you obtain your position data inside service). And don't forget to stop updating these objects when you're finished with something like:

```
private void stopPositionListner() {
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mGpsListener);
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mNetworkListener);
            Log.d(TAG, "Position Listener stopped.");
        }
    }
```